# Get min/max of Lat and Long leaflet map getBounds

Tags: leaflet

I have the bounding box of a map in leaflet with `map.getBounds()` which returns the `NorthEast LatLng` and `SouthWest LatLng`.
How do I get the minimum and maximum of both`Lat` and `Lng` from this bounding box. I needed to use this information to fetch all coordinates in my db that falls within these ranges.

Comment: `map.getBounds()` returns `LatLngBounds` object. See docs https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#latlngbounds how you can get rectangle bounds coordinates from it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.